# React JSX conditional call to web api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am beginner in a React JS. Can anyone help me to write a conditional API call in JSX. I am trying the following and it's not working

```
const GetOrPost = useState(true);

const GetOrPostDataFeed = (formdata)=>{

if(GetOrPost)
{
acquireToken().then((response) => {
                fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/file', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.accessToken }, body: formData })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => { console.log('Success:', data);  })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                        trackError(error);
                         });
                    });
}
else
{
acquireToken().then((response) => {
            fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/GetDetail/' + id)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => { console.log('Success:', data);  })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    trackError(error);
                });
        });
}

}
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Do you see the request in your network tab?

Comment: My apologies, that is my typos here. correct it.

Comment: Please consult the official react [documentation for useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to ensure you used the feature with the correct syntax before posting to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring state wrong way. You need update component like this:

```
const [GetOrPost, setGetOrPost ] = useState(true);
```

GetOrPost is the value and setGetOrPost is the function to change value of `GetOrPost`. You can read more in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)